# Regex starting with certain set of characters

Tags: regex

I have a requirement where the regex has to contains only certain set of characters .
For example requirement is that string can start with

**JIRA-<5 digit number> or PROJ-<5 digit number>**

This means allowed values can be as:
JIRA-12345
PROJ-98765

I tried regex as

```
(\JIRA-[0-9]+)|(\ PROJ-[0-9]+)
```

This seems to be not working, please suggest on how to proceed on this.

Thanks

Comment: Just `^(JIRA|PROJ)-[0-9]{5}$`.

Comment: Thanks this works but just a small edit instead of start it will be contains so what to replace ^ by ??

Comment: `\b(JIRA|PROJ)-[0-9]{5}\b` or `\b(JIRA|PROJ)-[0-9]{5}(?!\d)`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
\b(?:JIRA|PROJ)-\d{5}\b
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/CWxR8f/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    JIRA                     'JIRA'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PROJ                     'PROJ'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{5}                    digits (0-9) (5 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```